# function 'Func/Arity' already imported from 'Module'

Tags: erlang

I defined both area/1 and perim/1 in modules sqaure and circle.

I want to import and use them in another module. Here is my import statements:

```
-import(square, [area/1, perim/1]).
-import(circle, [area/1, perim/1]).
```

I got these error messages.

```
~/test.erl:4: function area/1 already imported from square
~/test.erl:4: function perim/1 already imported from square
```

I know erlang does not support namespace. But since we can qualify a function call by specifying the module (i.e. square:area vs circle:area), I fail to see how the lack of namespace is the source of the error here.

So, what exactly caused the above error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Erlang, "importing" a function from another module means being able to call it as if it were a local function, without the module prefix.  So with this directive:

```
-import(square, [area/1, perim/1]).
```

you could write `area(42)` and it would mean the same as `square:area(42)`.

However, if you include `area` and `perim` functions from two modules, it would be ambiguous which one you'd actually call when writing `area(42)`.

As you correctly note, you can always qualify the function call with the name of the module, i.e. `square:area(42)` and `circle:area(42)` - so I would suggest doing so consistently and removing *both* import directives.  This is also recommended by rule 6.6 of the [Erlang Programming Rules](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR26) - "Don't use import".

Comment: Thanks! I thought it is a good practice to use -import! Misconception  I carry over from other languages like java and python